# How to sync MongoDB with arango DB?

Tags: mongodb, synchronization, arangodb

I have transferred all data from MongoDB to arango DB. Now, I also want to sync MongoDB with arango DB. This means, whenever there is some change in MongoDB, the change must be reflected in arango DB as well. I have tried searching on the internet, but I could not find any useful methods.

Comment: There's no single right way to do this. These are two completely independent database engines. You'll need to implement something in your app to coordinate data between the two. And how you do that is very broad. Unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you please suggest any solutions?

Comment: I guess you 'll have to export or dump from arangodb the collections you want and just reimport them to mongodb at frequent intervals.
http://zaiste.net/2012/08/importing_json_into_mongodb/

It would be nice if you unloaded all the unused collections from arangodb after that to save some ram.